# Updating more than one span with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

At the moment the script

```
$(function() {
function update() {
 $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"balancefetch.php",             
    dataType:"html",             
    success: function(response){    
var trimmedResponse = $.trim(response.replace(/\s+/, ''));
if (trimmedResponse != $("#response1").html()) {
    $("#response1").fadeOut(200, function() {
    $("#response1").html(response); 
    $("#response1").fadeIn();
      });
}
else {
    }
}

});
}
```

Fetches some response and updates

```
<span id="response1">Loading...</span>
```

Whenever I try to add the same span with the same id so it can update both, it only updates the first. How would I be able to update both identical spans?
TIA

Comment: `id` should be different from each other. Use classnames instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
function update() {
$.ajax({
type:"GET",
url:"balancefetch.php",             
dataType:"html",             
success: function(response){    
var trimmedResponse = $.trim(response.replace(/\s+/, ''));
if (trimmedResponse != $(".response1").html()) {
$(".response1").fadeOut(200, function() {
$(".response1").html(response); 
$(".response1").fadeIn();
  });
}
else {
}
}

});
}

<span class="response1">Loading...</span>
```